# Do 2d CFTs define healthy 4d QFTs?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, conformal-field-theory, complex-numbers, poincare-symmetry

When doing 2d CFTs we typically complexify coordinates and formally consider $\mathbb C^2$, with the understanding that, in the end, we are to restrict to the real slice $\bar z=z^*$. If we do not impose this, but regard $z,\bar z$ as truly independent, does the resulting object define a healthy four-dimensional QFT? If so, is such theory Poincaré invariant? (i.e., does $\mathfrak{vir}\otimes\overline{\mathfrak{vir}}$ contain a subgroup isomorphic to $\mathfrak{so}(4)\subset\!\!\!\!\!\!\small+\ \mathbb R^4$?) Is it even conformal? (i.e., same as before but with $\mathfrak{so}(1,5)$.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Correlation functions in 2d CFT are single-valued on $\mathbb{C}$ but not in $\mathbb{C}^2$.
For example, in minimal models, four-point functions are of the type
$$ Z(z) = \sum_{i=1}^n c_i F_i(z)F_i(\bar z) $$
where $F_i$ is a hypergeometric function or generalization thereof, and $z$ is the cross-ratio of the four positions. In a free boson CFT, they look like
$$ Z(z) = z^a \bar z^a $$
where the exponent $a$ is generally not an integer.

If $z$ and $\bar z$ are no longer complex conjugates, these expressions become ambiguous. An interpretation in terms of QFT on $\mathbb{C}^2$ seems difficult.